# Trying to get multidimensional array to a query string

Tags: php, laravel, query-string

I am trying to build a multidimensional array to a query string for an API request.

```
    $key = env('GRAPHHOPPER_API_KEY', null);
    $baseUrl = "https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route";

    $formData = [
        'point' => [request()->input('point1'), request()->input('point2')],
        'key' => $key,
    ];
    $queryStr = http_build_query($formData);
    $url = $baseUrl.'?'.$queryStr;

    try {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $formData
        ]);
        $result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        dd('result', $result);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'trace' => $e->getTrace()
        ]);
    }
```

This is what it looks like when I DD out:

[image]

The error from API tells me it's expecting two points so I guess I am not building the query string collecting

Docs: https://docs.graphhopper.com/#tag/Routing-API

Error:

> resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:\n{\"message\":\"Specify at
>   least 2 points\"}

Comment: is there a documentation page for this API you can point us to? Also what is the **exact** error message from the API.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.graphhopper.com/#tag/Routing-API

Error: resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"message\":\"Specify at least 2 points\"}

Comment: Thanks, I added those details to your question, which is where they belong, rather than in the comments. Please do that in future if you're asked for more info. I've added what I hope is the correct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs page](https://docs.graphhopper.com/#tag/Routing-API) you linked to shows you how to structure the querystring data (see the testbed on the right hand side)

e.g.

```
?point=51.131,12.414&point=48.224,3.867
```

So there are two "point" entries, each containing two data items in comma-separated format.

Whereas you've got four separate "point[x][y]" variables in your querystring output. Your dd output suggests that `request()->input('point1')` and `request()->input('point2')` are themselves arrays. So what you've got is an array consisting of two further arrays, rather than a flat structure.

I think you need to write it like this:

```
'point' => [request()->input('point1')[0].",".request()->input('point1')[1], request()->input('point2')[0].","request()->input('point2')[1]]
```

Try that, I think it should work, or at least get you a lot closer to where you need to be.